If I use this proposition to get an elementary primitive of $f$, I think $g(t)$ must be a monotonic function. ("Calculus" by Takeshi Saito)
The following is from "Calculus" (in Japanese) by Takeshi Saito.

Proposition 4.3.9
Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function defined on an open interval $(a,b)$ and $g(t)$ be a continuously differentiable function on an interval $(c,d)$.
If $a<g(t)<b$ on $(c,d)$, then $$\int f(x)dx=\int f(g(t))g'(t)dt.$$

If I use this proposition to get an elementary primitive of $f$, I think $g(t)$ must be a monotonic function.
$\int f(x)dx=\int f(g(t))g'(t)dt=:h(t).$
$h(t)$ is a function of $t$ and it is not a function of $x$.
If $g(t)$ is monotonic, then $g^{-1}(x)$ exists.
If $h(g^{-1}(x))$ is an elementary function, this is the function what I wanted to get.
$g(t)$ must be monotonic if I use Propostion 4.3.9 to get an elementary primitive of $f$.
Is this right?
Check:
$\frac{d}{dx}h(g^{-1}(x))=f(g(g^{-1}(x)))g'(g^{-1}(x))\frac{d}{dx}g^{-1}(x)=f(x)g'(t)\frac{1}{g'(t)}=f(x).$
